# Is there a word for the beliefs of Baptists?

Tags: terminology, baptist

The beliefs of Catholics are Catholicism; the beliefs of Lutherans are Lutheranism; the beliefs of Presbyterians are Presbyterianism; etc. What about the beliefs of Baptists? It "should" be "Baptism," but that would be confusing. "Baptistism" is more understandable, but sounds wrong ("-ist" changes to "-ism"; they aren't normally combined).

Comment: Normally just "Baptist".

Comment: So "Presbyterianism and Baptist are the largest denominations in [area]"?

Comment: No, that's not grammatical. Presbyterianism is the noun for the movement, but not the name of a denomination, which would just be Presbyterian (Church). And to refer to the Baptist denomination, you'd usually say "The Baptists".

Comment: @curiousdannii so "The Baptists and Presbyterians are the largest denominations in [area]"? That definitely sounds better.

Comment: Baptists and Presbyterians are easy.  What does one call "*Church of God*"ers?

Comment: I attended a church that is baptistic in it's beliefs ....

Comment: Protestant Baptists?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a English language usage question

Comment: Baptists are not a denomination, by definition.  Baptists believe in the autonomy of each individual fellowship/church.  In practice this means that two Baptist churches could be, and often are, very different from each other in practice and/or belief, though they would agree in the acrostic beliefs highlighted in the answer of GratefulDisciple below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since one of the most visible characteristic of a Baptist church is adult baptism (instead of baby baptism in some Reformed churches), a word for the beliefs of Baptists would be [**"Credobaptism"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Believer%27s_baptism) or **Believer's baptism**.

If you can do with two words, you can use ["Baptist beliefs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baptist_beliefs), which more explicitly include other Baptist-specific doctrines.  The [*Wikipedia article*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baptist_beliefs) includes an acrostic BAPTIST:

> - **B**iblical authority (Matt 24:35; 1Pet 1:23; 2Tim 3:16–3:17)
> - **A**utonomy of the local church (Matt 18:15–18:17; 1Cor 6:1–6:3)
> - **P**riesthood of all believers (1Pet 2:5–2:9; 1Tim 2:5)
> - **T**wo ordinances (believer's baptism and the Lord's Supper) (Acts 2:41–2:47; 1Cor 11:23–11:32)
> - **I**ndividual soul liberty (Rom 14:5–14:12)
> - **S**aved and baptized church membership (Acts 2:41–2:47; 1Cor 12:12; 2Cor 6:14; Eph 4:3)
> - **T**wo offices of the church (elder and deacon) (1Tim 3:1–3:13)

Answer (score 1):

I frequently use the word “Baptistism”, which is a bit of an etymological perversion, but fills the gap left in the language. Anyone who hears me use it understands perfectly what I mean, and I have heard it used at my seminary unprompted. It’s a rare term but it exists and is generally accepted.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.